# php(?) inserts a space on large strings

Tags: php, string, whitespace

I have a big form that sends an email with its contents to the site admin. The problem I'm having is that at some point a space is inserted, and this causes markup problems. The email that gets sent is an HTML email, and sometimes a radom space character is inserted for example between a tag, so instead of `<li>` I get `< li>`. This is a problem because then the list item does note get rendered as a list item, but rather as normal text including the `< li>` tag.

I've noticed this behavior at least one other time. Once when I posted on a forum, a space was added in the middle of a word I've typed. Curiously enough, that word was mother in law, (Suegra in spanish). At the time it was funny because my first taught was that the administrators had played a joke due to the bad reputation of mother in laws, but this time it is not funny. This time this problem is really a problem because the markup gets all messed up.

Does anyone know why a space is added? It seems to be randomly. However, if I delete a character from one of the fields on the form, the space seem to not be added, or maybe it is added at a different location, like right before the `<` rather than in between the < and li thus not affecting the markup. Also, if I just echo the message that is supposed to be sent on the email, there is no space in the string at the location where it is added on the email.

*EDIT*
Here is the relevant code. It's quite large, but most of it is just constructing a string:

```
$subject = "New Quote Request";

$message = '<html><head></head><body>';

$message .= "<h1>New Quote Request.</h1>";
$message .= "<p>A new quote request has been submitted. Find all the submitted information bellow:</p>";

extract($_POST);
$message .= "<ul>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Company Name:</strong> $company</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Contact:</strong> $contact</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Email:</strong> $email</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Phone:</strong> $phone</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Alt. Phone:</strong> $cell</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Fax:</strong> $company_fax</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Address:</strong> $company_address</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>City:</strong> $company_city</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>State:</strong> $company_state</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Zip:</strong> $company_zip</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Shipping Information</h2>";

$message .= "<li><strong>Mailing Address:</strong> $mailing</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>City:</strong> $city</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>State:</strong> $state</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Zip:</strong> $zip</li>";

$message .= "<h2>Project Infomration</h2>";

$message .= "<ul>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Project Name:</strong> $pname</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Due Date:</strong> $duedate</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Project Specifications</h2>";

$message .= "<ul>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Quantities:</strong> $quantities</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Flat Size:</strong> $flat_size</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Finished Size:</strong> $finished_size</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Number of Pages:</strong> $num_of_pages</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Cover Options:</strong> </li>";//TODO self cover options
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Cover</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Weight:</strong> {$cover['weight']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Color:</strong> {$cover['color']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Name:</strong> {$cover['name']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Finish:</strong> {$cover['finish']}</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Text</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Weight:</strong> {$text['weight']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Color:</strong> {$text['color']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Name:</strong> {$text['name']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Finish:</strong> {$text['finish']}</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Other</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Weight:</strong> {$other['weight']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Color:</strong> {$other['color']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Name:</strong> {$other['name']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Finish:</strong> {$other['finish']}</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Coating</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Coating:</strong> {$coating['option']}</li>";
if(isset($coating['varnish']) && is_array($coating['varnish'])){
    foreach($coating['varnish'] as $val){
        $message .= "<li><strong></strong> $val</li>";
    }
}
$message .= "<li><strong>Additional Information:</strong> {$coating['aditional']}</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Cover</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Number of Colors:</strong> {$cover['num_of_colors']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>PMS#:</strong> {$cover['pms']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Bleeds:</strong> {$cover['bleeds']}</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Text</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Number of Colors:</strong> {$text['num_of_colors']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>PMS#:</strong> {$text['pms']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Bleeds:</strong> {$text['bleeds']}</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Other</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Number of Colors:</strong> {$other['num_of_colors']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>PMS#:</strong> {$other['pms']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Bleeds:</strong> {$other['bleeds']}</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Art</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Electronic Artwork Supplied:</strong> {$art['electronic_artwork_supplied']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Platform:</strong> {$art['platform']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Type of File:</strong> {$art['scans_required']}</li>";
if(isset($art['corrections']) && is_array($art['corrections'])){
    foreach($art['corrections'] as $val){
        $message .= "<li><strong>Corrections:</strong> {$val}</li>";
    }
}
if(isset($art['design_needed'])){
    $message .= "<li><strong>Design Needed:</strong> Yes</li>";
}
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Bindery</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
if(isset($bindery) && is_array($bindery)){
    foreach($bindery as $val){
        $message .= "<li>$val</li>";
    }
}
$message .= "<li><strong>Number of Drill Holes:</strong> {$bindery_['drill_holes']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Number of Pockets:</strong> {$bindery_['pockets']}</li>";
$message .= " <li><strong>Position: </strong> {$bindery_['position']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Size:</strong> {$bindery_['size']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Glue Pockets:</strong> {$bindery_['glue_pockets']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Business Cards Slits:</strong> {$bindery_['business_cards_slits']}</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Packaging</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
if(isset($packaging['type']) && is_array($packaging['type'])){
    foreach($packaging['type'] as $val){
        $message .= "<li><strong>Type:</strong> {$val}</li>";
    }
}
$message .= "<li><strong>Additional Instructions:</strong> {$packaging['aditional_shiping']}</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Fullfillment</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
if(isset($fullfillment) && is_array($fullfillment)){
    foreach($fullfillment as $val){
        $message .= "<li>{$val}</li>";
    }
}
$message .= "<li><strong>Fullfillment Requirements:</strong> " . nl2br($packaging['fullfillment_requirements']) . "</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Mail Services</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
if(isset($mail_services['type']) && is_array($mail_services['type'])){
    foreach($mail_services['type'] as $val){
        $message .= "<li><strong>Type:</strong> {$val}</li>";
    }
}
$message .= "<li><strong>Number of Inserts:</strong> {$mail_services['num_of_inserts']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>Size of Outgoing:</strong> {$mail_services['size_of_outgoing']}</li>";
$message .= " </ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Shipping Instructions</h2>";
$message .= "<ul>";
if(isset($shipping_instructions['type']) && is_array($shipping_instructions['type'])){
    foreach($shipping_instructions['type'] as $val){
        $message .= "<li><strong>Type:</strong> {$val}</li>";
    }
}
$message .= "<li><strong>Ship Via:</strong> {$shipping_instructions['ship_via']}</li>";
$message .= "<li><strong>FOB:</strong> {$shipping_instructions['fob']}</li>";
$message .= "</ul>";

$message .= "<h2>Additional Instructions</h2>";
$message .= "<p>" . nl2br($additional_instructions) . "</p>";


$message .= "</body></html>";

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


global $request_quote_email;
mail($request_quote_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Can we see your template? Or at least a bit of code?

Comment: We cannot answer without code. Please post the relevant PHP, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: We need to see some code to say what is wrong. Could be wordwrap, a text filter, etc. Without code we can only guess.

Comment: If by now it wasn't clear enough, we need some code ;)

Comment: I edited the question to add the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely scenario in my opinion is that the lines are being broken due to being too long.

Try inserting some `\n` in there, preferably after each `<li>` to keep line lengths reasonable.

Comment: It seems that adding that newline feed character solved the problem. I say it seems, because in order to be sure I would have to perform a lot of tests with a lot of combinations of field value lengths. But the test that I performed so far don't have the problem anymore. Thanks.